# Conditional Row-Wise Comparison in R over time span

Tags: r

Rep Example

```
ip <- c("127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.2", "127.0.0.1","127.0.0.4")
id <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
time <- c("2017-11-29 00:06:00", "2017-11-29 00:07:00", "2017-11-29 00:12:00", "2017-11-29 00:16:00")
language <- c("eng", "fr", "fr", "fr")
OS <- c("win", "OSX", "debian", "OSX")
df <- data.frame(ip, id, time, language, OS)
```

Go by seeing if condition one is true, if not, then go with condition two.

**Condition One**

Above is df

I want to match df$id other ids, such that if ip == same within 6 hours time on same date, the result should look like

```
 id1     id2
 a        c
```

The result can do in a different dataframe.

**Condition Two**

If above is not true then, check if language and OS match and if they do

In rep example case, because the IP of ID "a" and "c" match within 6 hours and OS and Language of "b" and "d" match, hence

resultant with both conditions true would be

```
id1   id2
a     c
b     d
```

Comment: What if you have more than two rows that satisfy the condition at once?

Comment: Looks like that what you want is the `ifelse` function.

Comment: @DavidArenburg then, we add another row in the result.

Comment: @EuGENE can you help write one for me?

Comment: The result is non sense, I'm just playing, but you could write: `ifelse (df$language=="fr", OS, time)`.

Comment: @EuGENE Why would you say that? :)